# Are there 3D data available of the official Raspberry Pi case?

Tags: case, official-foundation

I have a project, where I want to use the official Raspberry Pi case. However, I have to make some changes to it and I was wondering, if the Raspberry Pi foundation made the 3D data of the case publicly available such that one can 3D print it at home. I googled a lot but could not find them.

Does anybody know whether they exist and if yes, where?

Comment: I would have thought it is best to ask on the [official forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/) as that is more likely to be noticed by a Pi employee.

Comment: Well, I could have thought of this myself. I have posted the question in the official forums and will come back here as soon as I have an answer. Thank you @joan.

Comment: In general, 3D printing cannot replicate arbitrary cases because 3DP walls need to be thicker and injection molding is just more versatile. I'm not entirely sure why you would need an exact replica of the official Pi case. Thingiverse has lots of Pi cases that are 3D printable.

Comment: As @OyaMistAeroponics says, why can't you just download a generic rpi case and edit it to make it look like what you want? or why can't you just model your own case? see [this](https://all3dp.com/1/best-3d-printed-raspberry-pi-case-3d-print-3d-model/) for inspiration

Comment: I have a project in a company, where we want to sell larger quantities (approx. hundreds) RPis with a modified case. For example: We want the mSD card not to be removable and also to cover some ports. The official case is modular and really inexpensive and the idea was to use some of its components and only print the ones that we want to be changed. However, it is a valid point that the quality of the injection molted case is better than the 3D print. So, I will have a look at other 3D printable cases and see if some of them fits our needs more or less.

Answer (score 2):

According to [my question](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=217821) on the official forum there are no provided 3D data for the case. The reason is mainly that the case is created by injection molding and thus the model is not suited for 3D printing.